# Mat subtraction with OpenCV in Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I'm trying to convert some opencv code from C++ to Java, but I'm stuck at this code:

```
Mat matXyz; // some Mat
Mat result; // some other Mat
// ... set above mats to some values ...
result = Mat::ones(matXyz.size(), CV_32F) - result;
```

First, I don't really understand what the last line even does. 
Second, I don't know how to transfer this line to Java (OpenCV 2.4.6), as there are no overloaded operators like in C++, and I could not find any comparable method in the Java class (see [OpenCV Javadoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html)).

What is the best way to transfer this into Java?

Comment: you already found the docs, then you got lazy ..  http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#subtract(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)

Comment: I didn't look through the Core class.. should be more careful next time :D thanks anyway

Comment: @berak that link is already obsolete; OpenCV docs (especially Java ones) are notoriously prone to version changes, link rot etc.; nb. I wouldn't call one getting lost in them "lazy".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are matrix operations in the [org.opencv.core.Core](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#subtract%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29) class, including subtraction operators.

```
Mat endResult;
Core.subtract(Mat.ones(matXyz.size(),CvType.CV_32F),result,endResult);
```

The last line of your code creates a Matrix filled with ones, the same size as `matXyz`, where the data are floating point numbers. It is all described in the docs that you linked.